FFmpeg probe gives me a NumberFormatException
My code is :
FFprobe ffprobe = new FFprobe("pathTo/ffprobe.exe");
FFmpegProbeResult probeResult = new FFmpegProbeResult();
probeResult = ffprobe.probe(fichierTemp.getPath());

I have this error on some video files :
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Expected an int but was 109893054318340751 at line 160 column 37 path $.chapters[0].id

Can you help me please ?
Thank you

If you edit your question and provide the full stack trace of that exception (all of the at lines and all of the Caused by: sections), we may be able to determine why that exception is happening, and we may be able to suggest a fix.

They fixed issue in latest version. I'm not sure is it released yet. You need 0.8.1.
EDIT
It isn't released yet, but you can build one yourself. Source code is here
